# Google Maps CSS don't show map

Tags: css, google-maps, layout, google-maps-api-3

I have some problem with adding Google Maps to my project. When i get it into body tags it works. But when I have structure like this

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

it doesn't show anything. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `height: 100%;` is [always relative to the parent's height](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm). In your case, this is the nameless div, which has zero height, so `#map_canvas` will be the 100% of that, which is still zero. So the Google Maps won't show because the div has no visible height.

If you specifiy 100% on the parent div, it will work again. I guess you already have `html, body { height: 100%; }` if it works being simply in the body tag.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/wPeMg/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have html, body also at 100%?

```
html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
```