# Css and Google Maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to make a simple table with two columns in html, where one of the columns is the google map and another column another table with some information. I wanted the main table to occupy the entire screen, so I wrote it as follows:

```
<head>
     <script>javascript area ...</script>
     <style type="text/css">            
        table.tableMap{                
            position:absolute;                
            top:0;                
            bottom:0;                
            left:0;                
            right:0;            
        }            
        td.map{   
            width:100%;            
        }   
        td.table{
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
    </style>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <table class="tableMap">        
        <tr>            
            <td class="map">                
                <div id="googleMap" >
                </div>            
            </td>            
            <td class="table">
                 <p>I'm text in a cell.</p>
            </td>        
        </tr>   
    </table>    
</body>
```

But I'm having a problem that my map does not appear, it only appears if I change this:

```
 <table class="tableMap">        
        <tr>            
            <td class="map">                
                <div id="googleMap" >
                </div>            
            </td>            
            <td class="table">
                 <p>I'm text in a cell.</p>
            </td>        
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

To this:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
```

But I do not want a fixed size for my map, wanted him to occupy the whole cell to which it belongs. 
On stackoverflow I even found a link

[Google Maps CSS don't show map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156637/google-maps-css-dont-show-map)

that looked a bit like my mistake, but not helpful.

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following CSS:

```
#googleMap{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Then either apply a specific height and width to your `.map` cell:

```
.map{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Or, give it height and width of 100% but give the parent `.tableMap` a specific height and width:

```
.tableMap{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.map{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

In order to understand why, it is essential to understand that percentage and not specific unit widths are worked out relatively from the dimensions of their parent (or content), which in turn are calculated from their parent (or content) etc .etc.

Ask yourself this, if you specify height and width of 100%, what is it 100% *of*?

You can actually keep specifying 100% all the way up to the styles you give to `body` and `html`

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but I change the height and width of tableMap to percentage, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @memphis - that will be because a parent element has dimensions specified, in which case percentages are OK

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is have javascript grab the browser window's inner height and width with

```
    var width = window.innerWidth
    var height = window.innerHeight
```

And update the div size properties with the values those two functions return.

```
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.height = height + "px";
    document.getElementById("googleMap").style.width = width + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation did not specify that the node used to draw the map must be a `<div/>`.

When you want to have a map that occupies a complete cell, simply use the cell as node when you create the map.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/c4AS8/